# What statistical test should i use for the given scenario?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have an hypothesis that in people who have used both ios and android, a majority of them say 70% prefer android. I have a sample size of 50-60 users who have used both ios and android. What statistical methodology/tool/test should I use to confirm my hypothesis ?

Answer (score 1):

After interrogating each of the users about his/her preference, you can easily check your hypothesis using the one-sample z-Test for proportions. You can find it in most statistical softwares. Alternatively, you can directly apply the test and calculate the z value using the formula $z = (p - p_0)/\sqrt{p_0(1 - p_0)/n\,{}}$, where $p$ is the proportion actually observed (in your case, the proportion of users who prefer android), $p_0$ is the initial claim/hypothesis (in this case $0.70$), and $n$ is the sample size. Then you can search the p-value corresponding to the z-value using the standard tables or online conversion tools.

If the test provides a nonsignificant p-value, then it means that the null hypothesis (your initial claim) cannot be rejected.